# How to append Dataframe by rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I would like to merge (using `df.append()`) some python dataframes by rows. 
The code below reported starts by reading all the json files that are in the input `json_dir_path`, it reads `input_fn = json_data["accPreparedCSVFileName"]` that contains the full path where the csv file is store and read it in the data frame `df_i`.  When I try to merge `df_output = df_i.append(df_output)` I do not obtained the desired results.

```
    def __merge(self, json_dir_path):
    if os.path.exists(json_dir_path):
        filelist = [f for f in os.listdir( json_dir_path )]

        df_output = pd.DataFrame()
        for json_fn in filelist:
            json_full_name = os.path.join( json_dir_path, json_fn )
            # print("[TrainficationWorkflow::__merge] We are merging the json file ", json_full_name)
            if os.path.exists(json_full_name):
                with open(json_full_name, 'r') as in_json_file:
                    json_data = json.load(in_json_file)
                    input_fn = json_data["accPreparedCSVFileName"]
                    df_i = pd.read_csv(input_fn)
                    df_output = df_i.append(df_output)
        return df_output
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame(data=[], columns=self.DATA_FORMAT)
```

I got only 2 files are merged out of 12. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Best Regards,
Carlo

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html  please go through the link to understand more about working of concat, append and merge in pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set `ignore_index=True` when appending.

```
df_output = df_i.append(df_output, ignore_index=True)
```

Also you can concatenate the dataframes:

```
df_output = pd.concat((df_output, df_i), axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

As @jpp suggested in his answer, you can load the list of dataframes and concatenate them in 1 go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sure. Do you agree that my code is also correct?

Comment: yes, your code is correct as per what I can see. Can you print `json_full_name` in the while loop and see if all 12 file names get printed?

Comment: yes I did. it does. Moreover, I compared the number of rows that I get with your approach and mine, they are the same number.

Comment: and the number of rows do not match the sum of rows from individual files?

Comment: they do. That why I come to the conclusion that also my code is correct.

Comment: ok so the question is not valid anymore you are saying? `I got only 2 files are merged out of 12. What am I doing wrong?` this is resolved ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170311/discussion-between-carlo-allocca-and-vikash-singh).

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you do **not** concatenate dataframes in a loop.

It is much more efficient to store your dataframes in a list, then concatenate items of your list in one call. For example:

```
lst = []

for fn in input_fn:
    lst.append(pd.read_csv(fn))

df_output = pd.concat(lst, ignore_index=True)
```